# セレクトボックス内の要素を非表示にしたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select>
 <option>test1</option>
 <option>test2</option>
</select>
```

のtest1を非表示にしたいのですが、javascript 、jqueryで可能でしょうか？
firefoxでは、cssのdisplay:noneで非表示になりますが、IEでは実現できませんでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEのドキュメント[option element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877(v=vs.85).aspx)には

> Except for `background-color` and `color`, style settings applied through the `style` object for the `option` element are ignored. In addition, style settings applied directly to individual `options` override those applied to the containing `select` element as a whole.

とありスタイルを指定できない仕様のようです。

Answer (score 0):

非表示にするという意味では`display:none` をセットするというのが正しい処置だと思います。
なので、ＩＥは動作がおかしいように思います。
そうは言っても仕方ないので、
ＩＥでの処理を振り分けてＤＯＭ要素を削除してしまうしかないのかなと思います。（再び表示する場合は要素を差し込む必要がある）
削除自体はjQueryの`remove`メソッドで`$("option:first").remove();` (なんならIDを付けてＩＤ指定でセレクト)でできると思います。

ＨＴＭＬ文書自体を変更してoptionを１つ削除したりはしたくないので
一時的にＣＳＳを変更してＣＳＳのスタイルで非表示にしたかった。
というようなことなら、ＨＴＭＬの一部を削除するのではなくコメントアウトすることで無くすることができます。
`<!--` と`-->`で該当部分を囲む。
例：

```
<!-- <option>test1</option> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

一応、`hidden`属性を指定する事で消せるようです。
ただ下の様に`selected`で選択状態にしておくとユーザが操作するまで表示されていたりと、あまりスマートではありません。

```
<option selected hidden>test2</option>
```

また、この属性は古いブラウザではサポートされないでしょう。